# cuda invalid resource handle

Tags: cuda

What does this error mean? I can't seem to find ANY information on it. It occurs on a cudaEventRecord.

in the project header file:

```
cudaEvent_t cudaEventStart;
```

in a .c file:

```
cudaEventCreate(&cudaEventStart);
printf("create event: %d\n", (int) cudaEventStart);
```

in my one .cu file:

```
printf("record event: %d\n", (int) cudaEventStart);
cudaEventRecord(cudaEventStart);
```

the relevant output shows what the problem with the call is. cudaEventStart isn't a valid event resource in my cu file for some reason:

```
create event: 44199920
record event: 0
```

Details

- CUDA 3.2
- GTX 480
- 64-bit Win7

*I'm in the process of porting my code from linux to windows. It runs fine on the same card in linux, and there have been only a few changes. I defined `roundf` and added the following:*

```
typedef size_t off_t;
#define strtof(str,n) (float)strtod(str,n)
#include <float.h>
#define isnan(n) _isnan(n)
#define strcasecmp _stricmp
#include <io.h>
#define read _read
```

*It isn't clear to me why any of these things should affect cuda resources. Perhaps I'm building the project incorrectly somehow...?*

Comment: What are you doing that gives you this error? Any code you can show us?

Comment: @Bart sorry I thought it was at a kernel launch, but it's before that. Still tracking it down. While I am interested in getting this particular program working, the question still stands without code, don't you think? What things trigger this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An invalid resource handle usually means trying to use something (pointer, symbol, texture, kernel) in a context where it was not created. A more specific answer will require a more specific question, particularly which API you are using and how/if you are using host threads anywhere in the code.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks. I've added some code details. There are no host threads in the code (unless somehow they are used implicitly here in windows? - I'm not very versed in this windows environment with visual studio.)

Comment: @jmilloy: where do you do context establishment relative to the event creation and record?

Comment: @talonmies What do you mean by context establishment? I added details about where the event creation and record occur in my project... what other info would be helpful?

Comment: @jmilloy: At the driver API level, before anything can happen, a context must be established. This happens semi-implicitly in the runtime API. A nice way to force it explicitly is to call cudaFree(0) before you do anything else, then cudaGetDevice() to see what device you are using. Do this before you do anything else.

Comment: @talonmies - how does my call to cudaSetDevice fit in to this sequence?

Comment: @jmilloy: call it first. The key thing to remember is that it does not establish a context.

Comment: @talonmies The question has moved on to new topics, so i'm posting again